# Using Velo api in wix to update product image

Tags: javascript, velo

I-m trying to use the docs of Velo, to remove from product image by selecting it from gallery.
the officel docs is
`export function removeProductMedia(productId, media) { return wixStoresBackend.removeProductMedia(productId, media); }`

but it doesn't work, it seems that the problem has connection to "media" parametr in the function.

I try everything. and I'm alredy using function with the same syntaxt and with the same parameter that works
`export function addProductMedia(product, mediaData) { return wixStoresBackend.addProductMedia(product, mediaData); }`

you guys have any idea?

that my first time asking in stackoverflow after years of using

I'm passing for trying tamplate image
and the result "src.tolocalelowercase is not a function"
`{ "description": "", "id": "c3904a_3efe2c7fd11d480199986dd13ead530a~mv2.jpg", "link": "null", "src": "wix:image://v1/c3904a_3efe2c7fd11d480199986dd13ead530a~mv2.jpg/file.jpg#originWidth=720&originHeight=1600", "title": "", "type": "Image" }`